# Fatal error: Class 'Admin_Model_DbTable_Region' not found in Zend

Tags: zend-framework

I have a module named Admin in my zend project.I am redirecting to the action named viewAction of the controller named DeliveryCentersController by using

```
$this->_helper->redirector->gotoSimple('view','deliveryCenters','Admin',array('param1' => 'test'));
```

Now in viewAction of deliveryCentersController I have following:

```
 class Admin_DeliveryCentersController extends Zend_Controller_Action
 {

      public function viewAction()
      {
          $region=new Admin_Model_DbTable_Region();
          $this->view->dc=$region->getDeliveryCenters();
          // action body
      }

  }
```

here I have a class named Admin_Model_DbTable_Region in admin module in model/DbTable folder.
Now execution is redirected to viewAction of admin module but saying error as 
Fatal error: Class 'Admin_Model_DbTable_Region' not found in C:\Users\398853\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MST\application\modules\Admin\controllers\DeliveryCentersController.php on line 19
Plz resolve this error.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, it's called Zend Framework, not Zend. Zend !== Zend Framework. They refer to two totally different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this in your application.ini:

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] = ""
```

and add the Bootstrap.php file in your modules admin:

```
class Admin_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{

}
```

Comment: It worked.But i need to create bootstrap.php file everytime when I create a module?

Comment: each module must have its bootstrap! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your `model` directory should not be called "model" it should be called `models`.

If you **insist** on using `model`, then you should add this prefix to the resource loader by using something like this in your Bootstrap.

```
$loader =  $this->getResourceLoader();
$loader->addResourceType('model', 'model', 'Model');
```

Also, you shouldn't use the Action Stack. It is terrible practice, and rather than having a page which loads in 80ms (when optimised), you will struggle to get it under 120ms.

See this blog post on the [action stack.](http://www.rmauger.co.uk/2009/03/why-the-zend-framework-actionstack-is-evil/)

Comment: You mean to say that we should not use view helpers?

Comment: I renamed model to models but still the same problem occurs.

Comment: What is the path to the file containing the class `Admin_Model_DbTable_Region`? It should be: `application/modules/Admin/models/DbTable/Region.php`. Also be careful of upper/lower case. You are using the module name `'Admin'`; typically, this would be `'admin'` and the directory name would match. You should be ok with what you have, but it's another possible area of investigation for the autoload failure.

Comment: ryan, View Helpers are fine, but if you read the link I posted, you should see, that invoking the action stack, by using something like forward, creates another dispatch chain/loop. This is **very** heavy lifting. It's not something that in 99.9999999999% of cases, you can achieve the same thing by just using an Action Helper and a View Partial. I have never seen a use case where forwarding was the only answer.

Comment: @DavidWeinraub I am using netbeans and created module using inbuilt zf command tool in netbeans.
The location of Admin_Model_DbTable_Region is as follows:
application/modules/Admin/models/DbTable/Region.php
Plz suggest me to resolve this issue..Thanks for reply.

Comment: Yeah, @JellyBelly nailed it. Missing the module autoloader that performs mapping. Glad that you finally got it figured.